# Test sources in one project are not available to test sources in another project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

I have project A with a `source/test/java` folder and a class `com.testA.TestA`.

I also have project B with a `source/test/java` folder and a class `com.testB.TestB`.

[image]

Project B is included as a dependency in project A. This is the build configuration of A:

[image]

By default maven sets the "without test code" to Yes, but even if I change it to No and apply there is no difference.

These are the tests classes:

```
package com.testB;

public class TestB {}
```

```
package com.sourceB;

public class SourceB {}
```

```
package com.testA;

import com.testB.TestB; // The import com.testsB cannot be resolved
import com.sourceB.SourceB;

public class TestA {

    public void testMyA() {
        new SourceB();
        new TestB();
    }
}
```

The non-test sources from project B are indeed visible to project A's both test and non-test sources, it's only B's test sources that are not available to A's test sources.

Am I missing some configuration? I thought that if "without test code" is No then it should work.

I also tried adding the project through a maven dependency with default scope and a gradle dependency with `api` scope (because I need both test and non-test sources). It didn't change much.

Here's the POM of B:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>projectB</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Project A:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>projectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>projectB</groupId>
         <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
         <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I hope that directory is called `src/test/java`...and yes the tests classes are not available by default outside your own module. The question is why you like to have access to the test sources(classes) of a different module.

Comment: @khmarbaise They are utility test classes that help with testing shared code between other projects. Maven gives this example: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html. It's ok that test classes are not available by default, but the configuration says "Without test code: No", so why is it still not available?

Comment: Please show your pom files etc. furthermore change to the default locations...

Comment: @khmarbaise You don't need pom files to reproduce it. I created 2 simple projects in Eclipse, added one to the other in the build path, created 2 classes in their test folders, and tried to use one in the other. I can post that.

Comment: If your project is a maven project, then maven controls this and fixing it in maven is the right approach.  Fixing it for non-maven vanilla eclipse projects is different.  For maven, read this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html. I expect gradle will be similar but not familiar enough with gradle to give details.

Comment: @khmarbaise I added the poms.

Comment: @Taylor I added the poms. From the link, it seems that this is not really possible without a different project. I thought that there would be some configuration to export the tests.

Comment: Yeah, work is required in Project B pom to produce a test artifact.  (i.e. a jar containing the tests)